# Expanding a div container vertically to fit in another

Tags: html, css, expand

I've tried many examples in other questions but none seem to work for me. I'm simply trying to create a div container with a side bar 100px wide and will vertically expand with the container if it dynamically grows. See below;The inner div simply won't grow even when I set the height to 100%

[image]

My CSS looks this;

```
  <style>
    #outer {
        border:10px solid #7A838B;
        margin:10px;
        border-radius:30px;
        max-width:500px;
        min-height:200px;
    }

    #leftblock {
        background-color:#7A838B;
        width:100px;
        height:auto;
        border-top-left-radius:20px;
        border-bottom-left-radius:20px;
        margin-left:-10px;
        margin-top:-10px;
    }
    #inner {
        color:white;
        height:100%;
    }
  </style>
```

and my HTML is like so;

```
 <div id="outer">
        <div id="leftblock">
            <div id="inner">
                Test
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You have the child at 100% height. 100% of what height, exactly? The parent doesn't have a height and the grandparent only has a min-height set. (that's not the same as setting the height) 

If you can be a little more specific with how tall you want the inner div to be, then I could probably help a little more. But right now, you are essentially setting the height to 100% of 0.

Comment: Thank you for replying. As I said in the description, I'm trying to set the left block to be the same height i.e. touch the top and bottom of the grandparent container. I don't want the grandparent container to be less than 200px so I set the min-height. The parent (leftblock) container is set to automatically expand in height depending on what the inner block stretches to. Even if I set all three to 100% the inner blocks stays to the height of the text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It goes as @mmeverdies says,

> In order to set height:100%, the parent must establish a defined height too but if height property value is 'inherit', then the grandparent must set it. and so on.

You basically have two options here, either:

1) Define the exact height of the parent element. Then 100% height of the child will work then.

2) Stretch the child element with `position: absolute` like this: http://jsfiddle.net/r02nbmd9/ - note the `position: relative` of the parent and `position: absolute` of child.

```
<div class="parent"><div class="child"></div></div>

<style>
.parent { 
    position: relative; 
    width: 300px; min-height: 200px; 
    background: yellow; 
}
.child { 
    position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0;
    width: 100px;
    background: red;  
} 
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to set height:100%, the parent must establish a defined height too but if height property value is 'inherit', then the grandparent must set it. and so on.

to understand it take a look to this css.

example: for full browser height.

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
#outer {
  height: 100%;
}
#leftblock {
  height: 100%;
}
#inner {     
    height:100%;
}
```

by default the HTML height is 0. so, you must set the height property to other than 'inherit' of at least one parent.